# Dark mode of MacOS not working for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dark-mode

[As specified here](https://www.techradar.com/in/how-to/how-to-enable-dark-mode-for-google-chrome), I have enabled MacOS's dark mode however, the Chrome browser doesn't become dark. It's expected that webpages, toolbars, etc all become dark.

[image: dark mode nor working in chrome]

I wanted to avoid third-party Chrome plugins/extensions as they can inject scripts in my browser. Any idea why is the dark mode for Chrome not working?

The Chrome version I'm using is `Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Techradar puts up unacceptable cookie policies before you can enter, so is not a good link to post as a ref. Many people will not click through that ad/tracker-wall.

Comment: I don't use Chrome for macOS, does it support dark mode?

Comment: This was what Internet searches say. I was wondering why it's not working

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @fsb updated the question with version

Comment: Is your question about the browser/toolbar or the web pages themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome doesn't change the content of web pages to dark mode, but it can be made to.

It's experimental, so at your peril...

Put chrome://flags into the address bar and hit enter. Search for "Dark Mode", enable it, and relaunch Chrome.